# Is there any difference between apache2 and httpd?

Tags: server, apache2

Today I was installing `phpmyadmin` on `Ubuntu 12.04` and after a while a dialogue popped up stating what server I want to use; `apache2` or `httpd`

Are these, two different kinds of server?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**httpd** is the same as **apache2**. It depends on the OS you use. For example in **RHEL 6.2** it is called **httpd** and in **Ubuntu** it is called **apache2**.

Answer (score 22):

## TL;DR

They are the same application - just that some Linux distributions refer to it differently within package managers and config files. RedHat-based distros (CentOS, Fedora) refer to it as **httpd** while Debian-based distros (Ubuntu) refer to it as **apache**. Gentoo, strangely enough, mostly refers to it as apache - but config files have httpd in the naming conventions.

## Background

The application's development is managed by the **Apache Foundation**. Its name is actually **Apache HTTP Server**. It is often also called **Apache httpd** (http daemon) by the Apache Foundation. Colloquially, Unix admins have historically called it **Apache** and, even with the RedHat-based distributions, everyone already knows what you're referring to when you simply say **Apache**.

Comment: Ironically this TL;DR is longer than the accepted response.

Answer (score 13):

The directives used in `apache2` and `httpd` config files are slightly different, as well as the directory structure. It's advised to install `apache2` on Debian-based distros (`Ubuntu`) and `httpd` on RedHat-based distros (`RedHat`, `CentOS`, `Fedora`).

However, if you install `httpd` and its dependencies on `Ubuntu`, it works as well.